# Erro no gradle - design

Tags: android

Esse é meu gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.thiago.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

   }
  }


 dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
 {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile('com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.nispok:snackbar:2.6.1'
}



erro :
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

o erro já tá dizendo tudo.

No `compileSdkVersion` vc tá usando a versão 26;

E ela embaixo vc tá querendo usar a 25.3.1

muda o `compileSdkVersion` pra 25 que deve resolver seu problema.